# Vscode stuck on initializing datapack services for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

My Vscode instance on my WIn10 laptop is not being able to initialize the datapack services for my Salesfore extensions so the org explorer can not be accessed.
My vscode version is

[image]

I have the standard SF extensions, all just recently installed (they took a long time though).  All also on latest version of npm and the SF CLI (ie not SFDX cli)

My side bar looks good

[image]

However my footer bar just show 'Initializing datapack services' and the spinning icon & even after many hours is not progressing from there
[image]

Any idea what may be going on or how I can get further info to resolve this will be much appreciated